# Why the layout gravity of TextView is not working in horizontal LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-xml

This is the code which i am trying. but the textview which has layout_gravity right no shifting to right in horizontal linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="This Year"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHomeIncomeThisYear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="$0.00 USD"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All children of a LinearLayout are stacked one after the other. For your goal you can use FrameLayout, or you can add space as another child view object:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="This Year"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHomeIncomeThisYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="$0.00 USD"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

`Space` requires API level 14 or above. Otherwise you can use `View`.

Comment: thanks for you answer. but can you tell me why this is happening?  i am setting one child to left and another to right then it should be setup automatically.

Comment: It is special behaviour of LinearLayout. LinearLayout inflates child views one by one without any extra spaces except paddings and margins of child. If you use orientation="horizontal", then the right edge of the first view will be always touch with the left edge of the second view.

Comment: In my code Space has layout_weight="1" so it fill all free width. So Right edge of first textView touch left edge of Space and right edge of Space touch left edge of second textView. So main LinearLayout has not any gapes.

Comment: `<Space>` requires API level 14 or above. Otherwise you can use `<View>`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_gravity="right"` to `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. Remove `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use it using Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="This Year"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHomeIncomeThisYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:text="$0.00 USD"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the TextView `tvHomeIncomeThisYear` width to `match_parent` and set it's `gravity` and `layout_gravity` **to** `right|center_vertical` and `center_vertical` respectively :

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHomeIncomeThisYear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="$0.00 USD"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to change the parent view to something other than a LinearLayout, or insert additional views to act as spacers etc., just add a `layout_weight` property to your leftmost TextView with a value of "1" and set it's `layout_width` to zero (0dp):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="This Year"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHomeIncomeThisYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="$0.00 USD"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can then also remove both TextView's android:layout_gravity property, as they are not needed.